# How to distribute without the occurart tool?

Tags: add-on

I can use array modifier, but I want to align four different objects.
It could be a script. Please teach me.
And why was oscurart deleted

[image]

Objects I want to distribute.

[image]

Comment: Related: [Oscurart Tools: Not included in 2.91](https://blenderartists.org/t/oscurart-tools-not-included-in-2-91/1267891)

Comment: [Distribute Objects Addon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qf0cAajkkPM) Full disclaimer, I am the author

Comment: Distribute Object addon not provide 2.92 T.T

Comment: @Duarte Looks cool and easy to use :). Blender should really include this functionality by default tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create four objects. Enter the names of the objects at each end, A and D. Type B and C in the middle. Then spread the distance on the y-axis.

```
import bpy

#Compare y-axis distances

dif = bpy.data.objects["A"].location.y - bpy.data.objects["D"].location.y

#There are four objects, so do 4-1.

chunkglobal = dif / (4-1)

chunky = 0

#Sets the initial location value.

deltafst = bpy.data.objects["D"].location

 
OBJECT = bpy.data.objects["A"]

#In object, enter the location information for A.
    
OBJECT.location.y = deltafst.y + chunky

#Add the total length divided by the average length.

chunky += chunkglobal

#Repeat to the following object

OBJECT = bpy.data.objects["B"]
    
OBJECT.location.y = deltafst.y + chunky

chunky += chunkglobal

OBJECT = bpy.data.objects["C"]
    
OBJECT.location.y = deltafst.y + chunky

chunky += chunkglobal

OBJECT = bpy.data.objects["D"]
    
OBJECT.location.y = deltafst.y + chunky

chunky += chunkglobal
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the code and how it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)